# Adding a long list of files to a zipball with Python

Tags: python, git

I'm needing to export a Git repository as a zipball, including all untracked files. So far, I'm solving it by listing all untracked files with `git ls-files` like `repo.git.ls_files(others=True)`. I'm looping over each file and adding them to the zipball:

```
for file in repo.git.ls_files(others=True).splitlines():
    archive.write(repo_dir + '/' + file, file)
```

**The problem:** With a lot of untracked files, this can easily take minutes or even hours. What would be a faster approach to adding the files to the zipball? I'm new to Python, so the answer might be super obvious! :-)

Thanks!